# Countdown how to add milliseconds

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The below countdown clock works from seconds, minutes, days, months, year, how would I add milliseconds to this?

```
local secondsLeft = 3.154e + 7
-- one year


local clockText = display.newText("00.00:00:00:00", display.contentCenterX, 80, "font1.ttf", 60)



sceneGroup:insert(bg)
sceneGroup:insert(title)
sceneGroup:insert(summary)
sceneGroup:insert(clockText)



sceneGroup:insert(clockText)
local SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60
local SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR
local SECONDS_IN_MONTH = 30 * SECONDS_IN_DAY
-- assuming an average of 30 days per month
local SECONDS_IN_YEAR = 365 * SECONDS_IN_DAY

local function updateTime()
  -- decrement the number of seconds

  secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1


  -- time is tracked in seconds.  We need to convert it to minutes and seconds


  local years = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_YEAR) % 365)
  local months = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_MONTH) % 12)
  local days = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_DAY) % 30)
  local hours = math.floor((secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_HOUR) % 24)
  local minutes = math.floor((secondsLeft / 60) % 60)
  local seconds = secondsLeft % 60




  -- make it a string using string format.
  local timeDisplay = string.format("%02d·%02d·%02d·%02d·%02d·%02d", years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds)
  clockText.text = timeDisplay
end
local countDownTimer = timer.performWithDelay(100, updateTime, secondsLeft)
```

Comment: Try `Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", function(event) print(event.time)  end)` [Docs here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/time.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, maybe useful for you:

```
local sceneGroup = display.newGroup()

local totalSecond = 5 * 1000 -- 5 sceonds
local clockText = display.newText("", display.contentCenterX, 80, native.systemFontBold, 30)
--sceneGroup:insert(bg)
--sceneGroup:insert(title)
--sceneGroup:insert(summary)
sceneGroup:insert(clockText)



sceneGroup:insert(clockText)
local SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60
local SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR
local SECONDS_IN_MONTH = 30 * SECONDS_IN_DAY -- assuming an average of 30 days per month
local SECONDS_IN_YEAR = 365 * SECONDS_IN_DAY



function updateTime(msLeft)
    -- decrement the number of seconds
    if totalSecond >= msLeft then
        local secondsLeft = totalSecond - msLeft
        -- time is tracked in seconds.  We need to convert it to minutes and seconds
        local years = math.floor((secondsLeft / 1000 / SECONDS_IN_YEAR) % 365)
        local months = math.floor((secondsLeft / 1000 / SECONDS_IN_MONTH) % 12)
        local days = math.floor((secondsLeft / 1000 / SECONDS_IN_DAY) % 30)
        local hours = math.floor((secondsLeft / 1000 / SECONDS_IN_HOUR) % 24)
        local minutes = math.floor((secondsLeft / 1000 / 60) % 60)
        local seconds = math.floor(secondsLeft / 1000 % 60)
        local msceonds = secondsLeft % 1000
        -- make it a string using string format.
        local timeDisplay = string.format("%02dY·%02dM·%02dD·%02dH·%02dM·%02dS·%03dMS", years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, msceonds)
        clockText.text = timeDisplay
    else
        clockText.text = "Time's up!"
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameListener)
    end
end

function enterFrameListener(e)
    updateTime(e.time)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameListener)
```